# Angular ui-router throws transition error when clicking a link inside ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-grid

I'm using angular-`ui-grid` to display a table of facilities.

When clicking on the facility name, I want to link to the facility page with the facility id

In my `columnDefs` I have:

```
columnDefs = [
    {
        name: facility,
        cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">' + 
                    '<a ui-sref="facility({id : {{row.entity.facilityCode}} })">{{COL_FIELD}}</a>' + 
                    '</div>'
    },
    {name: facilityCode},
    {name: facilityState}
];
```

Where `facility` is my state, and I'll pass the `facilityCode` as a param.

All renders fine in the `ui-grid`, but when clicking a link to the facility state (which exists), I get the following error:

```
{
  "type": 6,
  "message": "The transition errored.",
  "detail": {stateService.ts?6000:490 TypeError: n.call is not a function
    at t.invokeHook (transitionHook.ts?c175:44)
    at t.runSynchronousHooks (transitionHook.ts?c175:94)
    at t.run (transition.ts?e0c6:430)
    at t.transitionTo (stateService.ts?6000:315)
    at t.go (stateService.ts?6000:207)
    at stateDirectives.ts?a57f:51
    at angular.js:19612
    at e (angular.js:5964)
    at angular.js:6243}
}
```

Nowhere in the `ui-router` docs do I see anything related to error types.

`facility` state definition:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('facility',{
        url : '/facility?id',
        templateProvider : ['$templateCache', function($templateCache){
            return $templateCache.get('../app/views/individualFacility.html');
        }],
        controller : 'facilityController',
        controllerAs : 'vm',
        params : {
            id: {value : '', squash: true, dynamic: true}
       }
    });
```

Am I encountering a hangup between `ui-router` and `ui-grid`?

Comment: try replacing `ui-sref="facility({id : {{row.entity.facilityCode}} })` with `ui-sref="facility({id : row.entity.facilityCode })`

Comment: @Aks1357 still get the same error.  The link renders fine with or without the double curlys, but error still shows :(

Comment: can you post you router definition code

Comment: @Aks1357 just added

Comment: `url : '/facility?id',` should be `url : '/facility/:id',`

Comment: @Aks1357 Still get the error.  Plus, I don't think that should matter (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120606/discussion-between-aks1357-and-tkwargs).

Answer (score 0):

My code worked after switching from version `1.0.0-beta.1` to `1.0.0-alpha.4`.

No errors of any kind and working great!